# Navbar active element changes color on hover when it shouldn't?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that I am building. The nav menu has the colors I want for a:hover and a:active, but when I hover on the active item, the color changes. I have tried inspecting the code, but the color it switches to is crossed out at every instance and I can't seem to be able to target the active's hover color. Here is what I have for the element:

```
.logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    background: #08A4EE;
}
```

All menu items are #08A4EE, active and on hover. However, when I hover over the active menu item the color changes to #1D302F and I don't want it to. When I look at the source I see the following:

> .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
>
> .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
>
> .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover
>
> {
>       <s>background: #1D302F;</s>
>       color: #fff; }

I don't know how to target the `:hover` of the `:active` menu item.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by adding

```
!important;
```

to the end of my css. I don't know why it switches to a different color on on hover for the active element, but this fixes the issue.

Here is what the line looks like now:

```
.logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .logo-nav .theme-nav .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    background: #08A4EE !important;
}
```